# Is there a way for me to change a DLL's targeted framework without having access to the actual project?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, dll, .net-framework-version

How can I update a DLL's target framework version without having access to its project library?

I have a third-party DLL that targets .NET 4.0.

I need this DLL to target .NET 4.5.

Any suggestions?

For example, my packages.config file has the following:

```
  <package id="FubarCoder.RestSharp.Portable" version="2.4.4" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="FubarCoder.RestSharp.Portable.Core" version="3.3.0" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
```

**Note how the targeted framework is set:**

targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81

Yet, my runtime is still pointing to .Net 4.0.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12181953/change-net-framework-target-of-compiled-executable Don't expect it to be bug-free...