# How can I make compiled .exe run in certain .NET Framework?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, .net-framework-version

I need to change my vb.net .exe to use the latest .Net Framework for Windows 10.  Right now, I believe it is set to .Net Framework 3.5 or earlier.  When my .exe is run on Windows 10, it gives a message that an earlier .Net Framework needs to be installed - this is a problem since my customer may not have access to the internet and sometimes this installation of the old .Net Framework fails.

I lost my code for my program; but I have the .exe.

Is it possible to change the .Net Framework required for this already compiled .exe?

I found a similar post here:
[Change .NET Framework Target of Compiled Executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12181953/change-net-framework-target-of-compiled-executable)

However, I did not generate a app.config file when I created the exe, and I only have the exe and not the code so I don't think I can make an app.config file using Visual Studio.

P.S. Another solution may be to decompile the .exe with JustDecompiler - but I'm getting some error messages with the decompiled vb project - I'm hoping I can get a simple solution with the .exe.

Comment: No, you can't change it in an already compiled .exe. You need the source, which you can compile to a specific target framework.

Comment: This is just one of the various reasons that you should be using source control. I suggest that you start doing so immediately, so that you will never again end up in a situation where you have lost the code for your program.

Comment: Download ILSpy, drag /drop the EXE into the app and Save Project As

Comment: Thank you everyone for your responses; Im will give ILSpy a try; and @user17922293: I was using source control, but I think someone maliciously deleted my project - it's the only way that my code in three different locations could be deleted simultaneously.  I don't know what happened.  But yes, I'm using github private repo now.  Thank you everyone.

Comment: You could probably write an `YourApp.exe.config` file manually, containing the relevant `supportedRuntime` node, that should just work

Comment: Your customer doesn't have access to the internet? Tell them to go to the coffee shop.

Comment: I found my code!  wow, saved me the time of re-writing everything.  @Mary, my customers are using computers that are in high security and have no access to the internet.  And the second it connects to the internet, there is a threat that the computer can have a virus, so they never connect to the internet.  At least that's as far as I know of the situation.  But thanks everyone for your help!